# SQL sum strange behaviour

Tags: sql-server

There is someone that could me explain why if I sum this in SQL management studio

```
| field |
---------
-41,07
-141,96
13,6
6
-13,6
-6
5,39
1,44
-6,83
41,07
141,96
```

with the simple the query

```
SELECT
      sum(
      field
      ) s
  FROM [table]
```

I get this result

```
|s|
---
-2,8421709430404E-14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your choice of data type. You have defined `field` as a `float`, and so you have stated you are happy with floating point values; which are not accurate figures. When you aggregate many floating point values, you are going to get a scientific notation value and are very likely to lose accurary. If you're not happy with that, don't use `float`.

As you can see, the below gives `0` for when the value is a accurate data type (`numeric`) and not when is using a floating point data type.

```sql
SELECT SUM(NotAFloat) AS SummedNotAFloat,
       SUM(CONVERT(float,NotAFloat)) AS SummedFloat
FROM(VALUES(-41.07),
           (-141.96),
           (13.6),
           (6),
           (-13.6),
           (-6),
           (5.39),
           (1.44),
           (-6.83),
           (41.07),
           (141.96))V(NotAFloat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce

```
  WITH CTE AS 
  (
      SELECT  -41.07 AS S UNION ALL
      SELECT  -141.96 UNION ALL
      SELECT 13.6 UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL
      SELECT -13.6 UNION ALL
      SELECT -6 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5.39 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1.44 UNION ALL
      SELECT -6.83 UNION ALL
      SELECT 41.07 UNION ALL
      SELECT 141.96  
  )
   SELECT SUM(C.S)
     FROM CTE AS C
```