# How do I write a trigger for such conditions? (3 tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables. When you add data to the Production table, the quantity of ingredients that are needed for this product is subtracted from the RawMaterialsWarehouse table.
The Ingredients table shows the ID of the product for which it is consumed.

And the raw materials should be subtracted from the quantity specified in the Ingredients table multiplied by the production quantity

```sql
CREATE TABLE RawMaterialsWarehouse (
ID int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
Name varchar(30) not null unique,
amountperunit float not null,
quantity float not null
);

CREATE TABLE Production (
ID int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
ProductsID int foreign key (Products ID) references FinishedProductsWarehouse (ID) not null,
Quantity float not null,
Date date not null
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredients (
ID int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
ProductsID int foreign key (ProductsID) references FinishedProductsWarehouse (ID) not null,
RawMaterialsID int foreign key (RawMaterialsID) references RawMaterialsWarehouse (ID) not null,
RawMaterialQuantity float not null
);
```

Briefly:

Production: here is the product id and its quantity.

Ingredients: here is the product id for which the raw material is consumed; the raw material id; and the amount of raw material per unit of product.

RawMaterialsWarehouse: here is the total quantity of raw materials.

When Production + : all raw materials specified for this product are deducted from RawMaterialsWarehouse.

Comment: FYI, storing something like a quantity or `amountperunit` (which I assume is the price) as a `float` is a *really* bad idea. A Quantity is a specific and accurate value, and a `float` is *not* a precise value; it's a floating point value. If you are using floating point numbers, you are saying you are happy for non-precise (and thus inaccurate) values. If you're summing something like a bunch of prices, you are very likely to get accuracy problem when aggregating them. For example, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067100/2029983).

Comment: The official documentation and available tutorials are very good. Have a go rather than getting someone else to do it for you.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your advice, I realized it as soon as I started working with the database

Comment: @DaleK I found information only for very simple and basic queries, can you tell me information about more complex queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_Production ON Production
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;   -- best practice to use these two

UPDATE rm
SET quantity = rm.quantity - i.Quantity
FROM
    (SELECT i.ProductsID, Quantity = i.Quantity - ISNULL(d.Quantity, 0)
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN deleted d ON d.ID = I.ID  -- for updates we take away the difference
) i
JOIN Ingredients ing ON ing.ProductsID = i.ProductsID
JOIN RawMaterialsWarehouse rm ON rm.ID = ing.RawMaterialsID
WHERE i.Quantity > 0;   --filter out zero updates

GO
```

Comment: i it's the inserted or Ingredients ?

Comment: `i` is the `inserted` pseudo-table and `ing` is the `Ingredients` table

Comment: @Asel you can see the aliases that Charlieface has used in the SQL: `inserted i` (`inserted` aliased as `i`) and `Ingredients ing` (`ingredients` aliased as `ing`).