# inventory calculations using triggers to calculate total product quantity when an order is placed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I am trying to write a SQL Server trigger which will subtract/decrement Quantity on hand (QOH) in the product table whenever a new Order is inserted. I have three tables Product, Orderline and Orders. I want to see how a trigger works when an order is inserted into the orders table. I am assuming when an order is placed in the orders table, the trigger will fire which will reduce the quantity on hand (QOH) in the product table depending on the order qty in orderline table.

```
    CREATE TABLE [ZEOTA.PRODUCT] (
      [PRODUCT_NO] number,
      [BRAND] varchar(15),
      [CLASS] varchar(20),
      [PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION] varchar(50),
      [UNIT_PRICE] number,
      [UNIT_COST] number,
      [PRODUCT_CATEGORY] varchar(15),
      [QOH] number,
      [ORDER_LEVEL] number,
      [ORDER_QTY] number,
      [BACK_ORDER] number,
      [AVAIL_DATE] date,
      [DAMAGED_QTY] number,
      PRIMARY KEY ([PRODUCT_NO])
    );

CREATE TABLE [ZEOTA.ORDERLINE] (
  [ORDERLINE_NO] number,
  [PRODUCT_NO] number,
  [QTY] number,
  [ORDER_NO] number,
  PRIMARY KEY ([ORDERLINE_NO]),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_ZEOTA.ORDERLINE.ORDER_NO]
    FOREIGN KEY ([ORDER_NO])
      REFERENCES [ZEOTA.ORDERS]([ORDER_NO]),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_ZEOTA.ORDERLINE.PRODUCT_NO]
    FOREIGN KEY ([PRODUCT_NO])
      REFERENCES [ZEOTA.ORDERINQUIRY_ACTION]([ADJ_QTY])
);

CREATE TABLE [ZEOTA.ORDERS] (
  [ORDER_NO] number,
  [EMPLOYEE_NO] number,
  [BRANCH_NO] number,
  [SHIP_METHOD_NO] number,
  [TAX_STATUS] char(1),
  [SUBTOTAL] number,
  [TAX_AMT] number,
  [SHIPPING_CHARGE] number,
  [TOTAL_AMT] number,
  [CUSTOMER_NO] number,
  [ORDER_DATE] date,
  [SHIP_DATE] date,
  [SHIP_COMP_NO] number,
  PRIMARY KEY ([ORDER_NO]),
);
```

What I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_SubstractQuantity ON orders
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

UPDATE PRODUCT
SET QOH = pro.QOH - ol.qty
FROM
    (SELECT i.ORDER_NO, Quantity = i.ORDER_NO- ISNULL(ol.QTY, 0)
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN ORDERLINE ol ON ol.ORDER_NO = i.ORDER_NO
    LEFT JOIN deleted d ON d.ORDER_NO = I.ORDER_NO
) i
JOIN ORDERS ord ON ord.ORDER_NO = i.ORDER_NO
Join ORDERLINE ol ON ol.ORDER_NO = ord.ORDER_NO
JOIN PRODUCT pro ON pro.PRODUCT_NO = ol.PRODUCT_NO
WHERE i.Quantity > 0;

GO
```

Comment: Why is your `TRIGGER` on `Orderline` yet the only object you reference in said trigger is `PRODUCT`? Also, does your table `PRODUCT` *really* only ever have one row?

Comment: What problem are you facing? What did you try already? If you want to show something in the question, don't add it as a link as people do not like to click on unknown links. If you have picture there - then include picture to the question. Ideally you need to add DDLs to the description with some sample data. These DDLs ideally needs to be as minimal as possible to solve your problem. People in SO like to help but do not like to do the work if you don't put any effort to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a trigger for such conditions? (3 tables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089456/how-do-i-write-a-trigger-for-such-conditions-3-tables) See also [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65781667/14868997] for a much better solution with no triggers but using indexed views

Comment: Your existing trigger is highly flawed: it assumes one row will be inserted, and is not referencing the `inserted` table

Comment: `varchar2` is NOT a sql server datatype. You will struggle if you do not know which dbms you are using / intend to use. I also see obvious date columns stored as strings - fix it or embrace the problems you will eventually experience with the poor decision.

Comment: @SMor sorry I used the data model from oracle. I have edited by question

Comment: @Charlieface I am new to sql triggers. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I don't really recommend building anything like this, because it's just an accident waiting to happen when something goes wrong... If you need store quantities on product level, an indexed view of ORDERS + ORDERLINE might be a lot better idea.